# How can i set right to left for asp.net respone.write?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm write simple web application, and show me this out put:
[image]

that shape use respone.write,every thing is ok but i want set respone.write to right to left,and i want this:
[image]

How can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: Why you don't use a server control or you can write it in an HTML tag which have `text-align:right;` ?

Comment: How can i write in html tag?@Aria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that but it is not recommended to use `Response.Write()` to add content to the page

instead it should be better use an HTML control or server control

In the web form:

```
<div runat="server" id="contentHolder" style="text-align:right;"></div>
```

In the code behind:

```
contentHolder.innerHTML = "your content";
```

the other way is write content like this:

```
Response.Write("<div style=\"text-align:right;\">سلام</div>");
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

Class your text element to:

```css
#rtl {
  text-direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<!--You can also declare arabic as lang, and right to left as dir in the opening html element if you wish to have for full documents. -->
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">

<div id="ltr"> I'm a line written left to right using standard CSS values.</div>

<div id="rtl"> I'm a line written right to left using standard CSS values.</div>

<!-- There are likely JS files to reverse the letters if necessary as well-->
```

Additional good resource: (http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir)

Comment: in asp.net response.write not write in DIV tag